# Expanding tiles layout using Angular in responsive layout

Tags: angularjs, responsive-design

I'm developing an Angular single-page app with a responsive layout. The current page I'm working on uses a tile-based layout that auto wraps extra tiles to the next row. The HTML is below and, in the responsive layout, it can show 1, 2, or 3 tiles per row depending on the width of the row (it positions them using floats).

```
<div class="tiled_panel">
    <div class="tile_1">...</div>
    <div class="tile_2">...</div>
    <div class="tile_3">...</div>
    <div class="tile_4">...</div>
    <div class="tile_5">...</div>
    ...
</div>
```

Now each tile will be given a "Learn More" button. The design calls for a block to expand **between the row of the selected tile and the row below**. This block will be the full width of the row and will be closed when the user closes it or clicks on a different Learn More button.

My first thought was to arrange the HTML as below using ng-if to hide or display the expander divs but I can't figure out the CSS needed to have it display between the rows.

```
<div class="tiled_panel">
    <div class="tile_1">...</div>
    <div class="expander_1">...</div>
    <div class="tile_2">...</div>
    <div class="expander_2">...</div>
    <div class="tile_3">...</div>
    <div class="expander_3">...</div>
    <div class="tile_4">...</div>
    <div class="expander_4">...</div>
    <div class="tile_5">...</div>
    <div class="expander_5">...</div>
    ...
</div>
```

My second thought, since I'm using Angular, was to somehow use transcluding or including to insert the relevant HTML into the appropriate spot. Again, I can't figure out how to identify where I need to insert the HTML?

I've tried searching around for other people's solutions to similar problems since I figured its not that unusual a requirement but I haven't yet been able to find anyone else who is doing this.

Can anyone else suggest what I need to do to identify the where to insert the HTML or how to generate the CSS? Or even suggest another solution that I haven't considered yet?

Answer (score 0):

Although I have 70% understand of what you mean, I think ng-class can simply solve what you've faced. The solution code is like below. And I setup [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yazaki/3Lsw9qwe/2/).

Html looks like this.

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="tiled_panel">
        <div>Tile 1 <a href ng-click="change_tile(1)">More</a></div>
        <div class="expander" ng-class="{'close': opentile===1}">Expander 1<a href ng-click="change_tile(-1)">Close</a></div>
        <div>Tile 2 <a href ng-click="change_tile(2)">More</a></div>
        <div class="expander" ng-class="{'close': opentile===2}">Expander 2<a href ng-click="change_tile(-2)">Close</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your controller code looks like this.

```
$scope.change_tile = function(value){
    $scope.opentile = value;
}
$scope.change_tile(0);
```

Css looks like this.

```
.expander{
    visibility: hidden
}
.close{
    visibility: visible
}
```

Comment: This is the basic idea of what I want to implement. The problem is that it breaks the tile layout. If the tiles are displaying in say rows of 3, then when the user expands tile 1, it forces the second and third tiles down. I need it to leave the tile row untouched and then appear below the row. And the tricky part is, that because of the responsive layout, I have no way of knowing how many tiles are in the row.

Comment: Understanding of what you want to achieve has progressed. Do you mean that you want to fix the position of tile whether the expander is open or not? If so, this might be the solution. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yazaki/3Lsw9qwe/2/)
I also updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, but I also need any other tiles in the same row to maintain their position as well. And tiles in lower rows will be pushed down by the expander.

Comment: You can add any other tiles as much as you want. Although my sample (just like your sample) don't use array to deal with dynamic number of tiles, you could do it if you want.
And as you saw jsfiddle sample, the tiles in lower rows will NOT be pushed down by expander. They are fixed to use 'visibility' of css.
Would you like to explain more details you want to achieve?